# Insplratlon: Is the GD font broken or does my browser not render it correctly?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

I was tempted to edit a post, because Insplratlon is not an English word.
I assume that as a graphics design site, the font that is used is probably the most perfect one that money can buy.

However, in my browser (FF 48.0.2) with my zoom level (100%) on my OS (Windows 7 SP1 x64) with my monitor (96 dpi at 100%) it's really hard to distinguish Ls from Is in headings:

[image: Insplratlon]

Here's the markup that's used in the answer where the screenshot was taken from:

```
###Insipration
```

And here's the markup rendered (not a bitmap):

#### Inspiration